# How can I copy object types in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am building an ASP.NET application that needs dynamic tables. That's another issue that I've already posted about (and gotten a pretty good response!). Now, I'm running into another issue - I want to add new rows to my table, but given that I will have 10-12 tables on one page, each containing different objects in their rows (text boxes, check boxes, etc.) I need a way of simply generically adding a new row that has the same objects as the first row in the table. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub AddTableRow(ByRef originalTable As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table)

        Dim originalRow As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow = originalTable.Rows(1)
        Dim insertingRow As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableRow
        Dim insertingCells(originalRow.Cells.Count) As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
        Dim index As Integer = 0

        For Each cell As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell In originalRow.Cells

            insertingCells(index) = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
            insertingCells(index).Controls.Add(cell.Controls.Item(0))

            index += 1
        Next

        insertingRow.Cells.AddRange(insertingCells)

        originalTable.Rows.Add(insertingRow)

    End Sub
```

But I'm getting a null reference exception at the second to last line,

insertingRow.Cells.AddRange(insertingCells)

...and I can't figure out why. Is it because the contents of each cell are not being initialized with a new object? If so, how would I get around this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The inside of my for loop now looks like this -

```
For Each cell As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell In originalRow.Cells
        Dim addedContent As New Object
        Dim underlyingType As Type = cell.Controls.Item(0).GetType

        addedContent = Convert.ChangeType(cell.Controls.Item(0), underlyingType)
        insertingCells(index) = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell
        insertingCells(index).Controls.Add(addedContent)

        index += 1
Next
```

Stepping through with a debugger, I see that this strategy is working - but the additional table row still doesn't appear...and still does when I do this statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your culprit may be this line:

```
Dim insertingCells(originalRow.Cells.Count) As TableCell
```

Confusingly, the number you specify in an array declaration in VB.NET is the upper bound, not the number of elements. So `Dim ints(10) As Integer` will create an `Integer()` array with **eleven** elements, not ten (10 will be the highest index of the array).

Try this instead:

```
Dim insertingCells(originalRow.Cells.Count - 1) As TableCell
```

Comment: That solved the runtime error issue, but apparently objects are still not being copied - no new row is added to my table. I commented out that code and plugged in a static addition of a table row, and a new row was then added to my table.

Something is still amiss here. Thanks for your help so far! =)